# Override a theme function in a child theme?

Tags: functions, theme-development, function-exists

Most if not all of the answers to this question are pretty old, or are for edge cases.

I have a child theme for a commercial theme ("Total"). The parent theme's functions.php loads functions from several php files in its "framework" folder.  The function I am targeting is in fonts.php, called `wpex_standard_fonts`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_standard_fonts' ) ) {
function wpex_standard_fonts() {
    return array(
        "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
        "Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif",
         ...
         );
   }
}
```

So, from what I have googled, I take this add to my child theme functions.php with my changes to it, right? So I add my custom font to the array.

But when I go to the admin tool, my custom font menu item is not there.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Do you make the check of "if function exists" in your child theme, or this is a check in the parent theme?

Comment: it was in parent, but I also did it in the child theme.  I heard that's it's good practice.

Comment: Override parent theme functions is quite easy and it seems that you are doing right. But we can not know why it is not working in your particular case for the "font menu"; we don't know how that "font menu" works or how it is coded. You should ask to the theme developer.

Comment: Thanks.  As long as I did it right.  I will check with the dev to see if that's the right function to target.

Comment: I din't try it, but thinking, `if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_standard_fonts' ) ) {` will return **yes there is a function in the parent theme** - isn't that?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam it will first check child theme function and will return yes there is a function in the child theme, so the parent theme function will never run.I have done this before.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Child Theme, the functions.php file in there is loaded **before** the parent theme's functions.

So, if you define `some_function()` in the Child Theme, any declaration of that function in the parent theme will fail. If the parent theme is using a `function_exists()` to check if `some_function()` is defined, it should find the function as already being defined, so the parent function will not be loaded.

So, your code to check if the `function_exists()` is not really needed - since you are in a Child Theme. Only if the parent theme does not do a `function_exists` for `some_function()` will there be issues - possibly fatal errors that will disrupt the site.